# how to switch on/off a circuit from python?

Tags: python, wxpython, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I has a circuit containing mcp3008 and a rain sensor module that read analog data and send digital data to raspberry pi.I what to create another circuit that has a button that can turn on and off the rain sensor circuit. the rain sensor circuit is connected to 5v pin on raspberry pi. can anyone help me on how to turn on and off the rain sensor circuit?

This is the web that I found about how to on/off another circuit from it:
http://www.barryhubbard.com/raspberry-pi/howto-pn2222a-npn-gpio-controlled-simple-transistor-circuit-for-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #Get's GPIO module
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MCP3008
#Define your MCP3008 SPI stuff here
CLK = 18 # Change these values to then pins you are using
MISO = 20
MOSI = 21
CS = 8
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK, cs=CS, miso=MISO, mosi=MOSI)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #sets mode
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Button Pin
input_state = GPIO.input(22) #Get's button input
while True:
      if input_state == 1:
            break
      else:
          continue
```

And there's your code!! I also happen to use the MCP3008 module for a windsensor! Happy programming!

EDIT:
    To read one channel simply
    
    `import Adafruit_SPI as SPI
    import Adafruit_MCP3008
    CLK = 18
    MISO = 20
    MOSI = 21
    CS = 8
    mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK, cs=CS, miso=MISO, mosi=MOSI)
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
        values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)
        CHANNEL_ZERO = '{0:>4'.format(*values)`

Comment: Also my rain sensor program is containing wxpython module that make it has only one main loop. I use timer to update the interface and i did't use threading as i'm a beginner in python. Also can you help me on my question before this question on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459949/how-to-change-my-wxpython-program-that-read-and-display-rain-sensor-data-from-mc

Comment: I confuse with the solution given by other as when i try it it read multiple channel as i only want it to read one channel and for your solution above what i has to do about the pin on rain sensor as the rain sensor module use 5v pin and if i change it to gpio pin it can only get 3v from the gpio pin?

Comment: import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI

Comment: The MCP3008 can only take 3.3 volts man. I can't help you there.